# How can I reference a named Excel column from an Outlook VBA procedure?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The project I'm working on involves several Outlook VBA procedures that access two Excel workbooks.  Without going into too much detail, I am able to access a cell using something like ".Cell(RowNr, 3)" where RowNr is an integer row number.

All columns are named though and I think I ought to be able to use those names in an Outlook VBA procedure (thus ensuring that there will never be a need to insert a new column).  I know how to reference a column by name in an Excel macro but haven't been able to find the proper syntax for doing this from an Outlook VBA procedure.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you know how to access Excel from Outlook, since you mentioned "several Outlook VBA procedures" that do so.  Assuming you have a `Worksheet` object named `sh`:

```
Dim r as Range
set r = sh.Range("<whatever the column name is>")
```

gives you a reference to that column in `r`.  You can then access `r.Cells(i)` for the value in the `i`th row.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!  The information you provided was exactly what I needed.  I made a few changes and the function worked perfectly the first time.

Comment: @RiverKing Much appreciated! :)